# R - Regex to Extract URL from Text

Tags: regex, r

I have some data in R Data Frame Column as below. I am trying to keep the `url` and remove everything else if I get a `url`, else keep the column unchanged.

The problem is that there could be leading spaces/no leading spaces, `*` characters, Ending Extra Words or `$` etc etc.

```
kick-boxer.com
easy hotel.com.my-kl s
weebly-charge.com
vietnamtouronsal e.com
mes*wix.com*113963740
borderlinx.com
www.aliexpress.com
www.aliexpress.com
skr*skrill.com
```

Also I am not able to set a possessive option in `R`. Basically to not give up characters that I has held.

```
gsub( '(^|.*?|\\s+)(http\\:\\/\\/|https\\:\\/\\/)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*\\.)+(org|edu|com|co.sg|info)(.*?|$|\\s+)' ,'\\2\\3\\4\\5', test$url)
```

Problem is that the leading `(^|.*?|\\s+)` and trailing `(.*?|$|\\s+)` due to the `.*` greedily eat up the characters - Leaving me with "`a.com`"

Any suggestion?

Comment: What would the expected result be?

Comment: Just the Website. Stripped of everything before and after it.

Comment: @myloginid You're referring to *"the problem"*, but it's not clear what *"the problem"* actually is. Can you specify where it is failing? ... You're repeating the 3rd group with `+`, and the backreference will be overwritten with the last repetition of that group, omitting text in `\\3`, but that doesn't seem to be what you're describing.

Comment: @myloginid You can post that as an aswer to your question (using code formatting, as it turns unreadable in a comment). [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer to make @mylogind's comments parseable.

With test data

```
kick-boxer.com
easy hotel.com.my-kl s
weebly-charge.com
vietnamtouronsal e.com
mes*wix.com*113963740
borderlinx.com
www.aliexpress.com
www.aliexpress.com
skr*skrill.com
```

and seeking to extract only the proper domains, the following multi-step solution was proposed.

```
test$rem4 = gsub( '(?i)(\*)' ,' * ', test$rem4) 
test$rem4 = gsub( '(?i)^(.*)(\\.)([a-z]{2,6})(.*)$' ,'\\1\\2\\3 \\4', test$rem4) 
test$website1 = gsub( '^(www\\.)?([a-z0-9]{2,}\\.)+(org|edu|com|co\\.sg|info|co\\.[a-z]{2}|sg|me|net)\\s+(.‌​*|$)' ,'\\1\\2\\3', test$rem4) 
test$website2 = gsub( '^(.*)\\s+(www\\.)?([a-z0-9]{2,})(\\.)(org|edu|com|co\\.sg|info|co\\.[a-z]{2}|sg|me|n‌​et)$' ,'\\2\\3\\4\\5', test$rem4)     
test$website3 = gsub( '^(.*)\\s+(www\\.)?([a-z0-9]{2,})(\\.)(org|edu|com|co\\.sg|info|co\\.[a-z]{2}|sg|me|n‌​et)\\s+(.*)$' ,'\\2\\3\\4\\5', test$rem4)
```